# TypeScript reports error on form attribute of button element

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

Although in the [MDN page of HTML button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attributes) there is an attribute of `form` that serves the purpose of connecting submit button to the form to which it belongs to (they do not need to be in the parent child hierarchy) TypeScript is giving me error when I create a button like this:

```
<button type='submit' form='createCustomerForm'>
```

This is a full TS error message:

> TS2322: Type 'string | HTMLFormElement | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.  index.d.ts(2083, 9): The expected type comes from property 'form' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>'

Considering that value of this button should be string, an id of the form itself, I do not understand really this error, nor its message.

My question is can someone explain what is the reason why the type of value passed to this attribute can be `null` or the `HTMLFormElement`. To me this does not make a lot of sense. Also, how to fix this error message without disabling ts?

You can find code sandbox with this error following [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-architecture-3hv7g9?file=/src/App.tsx)

Redacted, but code with reproducible error is here:

```
import { MouseEventHandler, PropsWithChildren, ReactNode } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

type ButtonType = {
  inactive?: boolean;
  onClick?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined;
  text: string | ReactNode;
  type?: "button" | "submit" | "reset";
} & Partial<HTMLButtonElement>;

const Button = ({ inactive, text, type = "button", ...rest }: ButtonType) => (
  <button disabled={inactive} type={type} {...rest}>
    {text}
  </button>
);

const FormDialog = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => (
  <dialog>
    <form id="createCustomerForm">
      <header>
        <h4>Create customer</h4>
        <button autoFocus onClick={() => {}} type="button">
          X
        </button>
      </header>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <footer>
        <div>
          <Button onClick={() => {}} text="close" type="button" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button form="createCustomerForm" text="submit" type="submit" />
        </div>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </dialog>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <FormDialog>
      <input type="text" id="customerName" />
    </FormDialog>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi. I edited question by adding code sandbox link at the bottom.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) adding a link, please add the code causing the error to the question itself, as mentioned in [ask]. Right now, the answer makes no sense without following the link, and questions (and answers) on Stack Overflow should be self-contained (although answers can depend on questions' contents of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Partial<HTMLButtonElement>`, there are two options:

- `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'button'>`
- `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`

```
type ButtonType = {
    inactive?: boolean;
    onClick?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined;
    text: string | ReactNode;
    type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
} & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'button'>;
```

Or

```
type ButtonType = {
    inactive?: boolean;
    onClick?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined;
    text: string | ReactNode;
    type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
} & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76627652-s6nlst?file=/src/App.tsx)

---

Let's see the `HTMLButtonElement` interface:

`node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
interface HTMLButtonElement extends HTMLElement {
    disabled: boolean;
    /** Retrieves a reference to the form that the object is embedded in. */
    readonly form: HTMLFormElement | null;
    // ...
}
```

The `HTMLButtonElement` interface provides properties and methods for [HTMLButtonElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement), it's DOM, not the interface for HTML `<button>` tag's attributes. That's why the `form` property is a read-only property and its value is a [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

The `ButtonHTMLAttributes` interface provides the attributes for [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) html tag(a built-in component in React).

`node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index.d.ts`:

```
interface ButtonHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    disabled?: boolean | undefined;
    form?: string | undefined;
    //...
}
```

`form` is `string` type, its value is a form element's id.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and the solution. I marked the answer as correct.